# Listbox on Unbound MainForm Linked to Bound Subform Producing 3021 (No Current Record) error

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, listbox

There are tons of 3021 error Q&As, but have not found this one.

**Setup:**

Blank Access 2016 DB

Add Plain table (1 ID column, 1 Title (String) Column)

Create a form based on the table, one display textbox.  Save & Close

Create a second form.  Add a listbox, row source is the Plain table, 2 columns, first column width 0.

Add the first form to the second form as a subform.  Link the listbox to the subform using Master/CHild (Master = List1, Child = ID)

Basically setup a standard use listbox on main form to control navigation to a specific detail child record on the subform.

In the Subforms "Current" event, add "debug.print Me.Recordset.Fields("ID")"

**Effects**

On first loading the second form, will get a 3021 record not found error.  Not surprising.

On first selecting an item in the listbox, no error.

On second time selecting an item in the listbox, 3021 error comes up.

**Questions**

Reproducible for others (I suspect not, this seems such a standard setup I'm guessing I'm dealing with corrupted Access install... but?)

If others can reproduce, ideas for what is the cause, particularly the difference between first selection and second selection?  Alternative setups?

Comment: Why have the Debug line anyway? Why reference Recordset property? `Debug.Print Me!ID`

Comment: I missed adding at the top this is a stripped down minimally reproducible example. There are things I usually do to configure the subform based on contents of the current record (eg lookup something in another table not part of the form base), but if the 'current' event is producing a no current record error, I have no way to take actions based on the value of the current record in the subform. One work around is to reach up to the main form and grab value from the listbox itself but that introduces tight binding between the subform and main form and seems unnecessary given the recordset.

Comment: Well, my example code does print the ID of current record.

Comment: Thank you @June7.... your comment pointed me on a fruitful research track that gave me a useful workaround (my specific use case has the fieldname of interest stored in a variable). If you had an explanation of why the disconnect between the two notations (or more fundamentally between the controls and the recordset) I would be happy to accept an answer (or anyone else's) in preference to my own just posted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @June7 comment I dug a little deeper. For reasons I do not understand, there is a disconnect between the sub forms recordset object and the controls on the subform.

Can't easily provide links on phone, but searches on bang vs dot notation provided hints (David Fenton answers) that the Me!Fieldname notation is really late bound shorthand for Me.controls("fieldname"), and that reference correctly works (points to the updated value of the listbox on the main form in the subforms current event)

Short form for anyone who finds this: use Me!Fieldname or Me.controls(variableContainingFieldname) notation to refer to field values in the underlying recordset in the subforms current event to avoid a 3021 error)